# How Do I Fix This Numpy Error: Too Many Indices For Array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am working with some old code that works in Python2 but raises an error in Python3. The error stems from an np array in the module. The array is below.

if I assign the np array to a variable called test, and call test[:,0], I get an error "IndexError: too many indices for array."

The byte array is created using an np.asarray() function on bytes coming from a calibration table on a piece of hardware. This error is particularly confusing to me, as it works perfectly fine in Python2.

How can I fix this issue?

```
>>>test=b'[[0, 0, 0], [0.0, 0.01, -1.0], [0.1, 0.01, 8.0], [0.2, 0.02, 10.0], [0.3, 0.02, 12.0], [0.4, 0.03, 14.0], [0.5, 0.04, 16.0], [0.6, 0.05, 18.0], [0.7, 0.06, 19.0], [0.8, 0.08, 21.0], [0.9, 0.11, 23.0], [1.0, 0.24, 24.0], [1.1, 3.82, 25.0], [1.2, 9.09, 26.0], [1.3, 14.36, 27.0], [1.4, 19.78, 28.0], [1.5, 25.11, 30.0], [1.6, 30.57, 31.0], [1.7, 36.01, 31.0], [1.8, 41.51, 33.0], [1.9, 47.07, 34.0], [2.0, 52.57, 35.0], [2.1, 58.13, 36.0], [2.2, 63.74, 37.0], [2.3, 69.46, 37.0], [2.4, 74.89, 38.0], [2.5, 80.63, 39.0]]'

>>>test2 = np.asarray(test)

>>>test2[:,0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

EDIT: Added code for clarification. Also, the issue seems to be that in Python3, type(test) = bytes, but in python2 type(test) = list.

Comment: The code you posted is not complete. Please add a complete working example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I edited, was that helpful?

Comment: The `test2` contains is an array containing only 1 value. You have to find a way to convert the string to numpy values. From the doc, I've read about `np.fromstring` but it throws a deprecation warning with the actual version of numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample is incomplete. I suppose it shoud be:

```
test = b'[...]'
```

(`...` stands for your content between brackets, I added `'` at the end).

Note that *test* is of *bytes* type.

When you run `test2.ndim` the result is `0`, so (in the recent version of
*Numpy*) it is a **0-D** array.

To get its content (a scalar), you can run: `test2.item()`, getting
back a **bytes** object:

```
b'[...]'
```

You can transcode it into an "ordinary" (UTF-8) string, running:

```
test2.item().decode('utf-8')
```

but it is still a **string**, not an array.

To get "ordinary" **2-D** *Numpy* array, you can `import ast` and then run:

```
test3 = np.array(ast.literal_eval(test2.item().decode('utf-8')))
```

(*ast.literal_eval* is more safe than "ordinary" *eval*) or starting
from *test*:

```
test3 = np.array(ast.literal_eval(test.decode('utf-8')))
```

Now you can run: `test3[:,0]`, getting what you want, i.e.:

```
array([0. , 0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. , 1.1,
       1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2. , 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4,
       2.5])
```

Comment: You're right, I missed the trailing single quote when I copied and pasted. I am going to try ast, I think you might have solved my problem though!

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this working in Py2?

```
In [290]: test=b'[[0, 0, 0], [0.0, 0.01, -1.0], [0.1, 0.01, 8.0], [0.2, 0.02, 10.0], [0.3
     ...: , 0.02, 12.0], [0.4, 0.03, 14.0], [0.5, 0.04, 16.0], [0.6, 0.05, 18.0], [0.7, 0
     ...: .06, 19.0], [0.8, 0.08, 21.0], [0.9, 0.11, 23.0], [1.0, 0.24, 24.0], [1.1, 3.82
     ...: , 25.0], [1.2, 9.09, 26.0], [1.3, 14.36, 27.0], [1.4, 19.78, 28.0], [1.5, 25.11
     ...: , 30.0], [1.6, 30.57, 31.0], [1.7, 36.01, 31.0], [1.8, 41.51, 33.0], [1.9, 47.0
     ...: 7, 34.0], [2.0, 52.57, 35.0], [2.1, 58.13, 36.0], [2.2, 63.74, 37.0], [2.3, 69.
     ...: 46, 37.0], [2.4, 74.89, 38.0], [2.5, 80.63, 39.0]]'                            
In [291]: test                                                                           
Out[291]: b'[[0, 0, 0], [0.0, 0.01, -1.0], [0.1, 0.01, 8.0], [0.2, 0.02, 10.0], [0.3, 0.02, 12.0], [0.4, 0.03, 14.0], [0.5, 0.04, 16.0], [0.6, 0.05, 18.0], [0.7, 0.06, 19.0], [0.8, 0.08, 21.0], [0.9, 0.11, 23.0], [1.0, 0.24, 24.0], [1.1, 3.82, 25.0], [1.2, 9.09, 26.0], [1.3, 14.36, 27.0], [1.4, 19.78, 28.0], [1.5, 25.11, 30.0], [1.6, 30.57, 31.0], [1.7, 36.01, 31.0], [1.8, 41.51, 33.0], [1.9, 47.07, 34.0], [2.0, 52.57, 35.0], [2.1, 58.13, 36.0], [2.2, 63.74, 37.0], [2.3, 69.46, 37.0], [2.4, 74.89, 38.0], [2.5, 80.63, 39.0]]'
In [292]: np.asarray(test)                                                               
Out[292]: 
array(b'[[0, 0, 0], [0.0, 0.01, -1.0], [0.1, 0.01, 8.0], [0.2, 0.02, 10.0], [0.3, 0.02, 12.0], [0.4, 0.03, 14.0], [0.5, 0.04, 16.0], [0.6, 0.05, 18.0], [0.7, 0.06, 19.0], [0.8, 0.08, 21.0], [0.9, 0.11, 23.0], [1.0, 0.24, 24.0], [1.1, 3.82, 25.0], [1.2, 9.09, 26.0], [1.3, 14.36, 27.0], [1.4, 19.78, 28.0], [1.5, 25.11, 30.0], [1.6, 30.57, 31.0], [1.7, 36.01, 31.0], [1.8, 41.51, 33.0], [1.9, 47.07, 34.0], [2.0, 52.57, 35.0], [2.1, 58.13, 36.0], [2.2, 63.74, 37.0], [2.3, 69.46, 37.0], [2.4, 74.89, 38.0], [2.5, 80.63, 39.0]]',
      dtype='|S517')
```

Did you look at `test2` before trying to use it?  You have just wrapped one big string in `np.array`; look at the shape and dtype.

You can make an array from the text if applied as:

```
In [293]: np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0.0, 0.01, -1.0], [0.1, 0.01, 8.0], [0.2, 0.02, 10.0], [0
     ...: .3, 0.02, 12.0], [0.4, 0.03, 14.0], [0.5, 0.04, 16.0], [0.6, 0.05, 18.0], [0.7,
 ....
     ...: 9.46, 37.0], [2.4, 74.89, 38.0], [2.5, 80.63, 39.0]])                          
Out[293]: 
array([[ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00],
       [ 0.000e+00,  1.000e-02, -1.000e+00],
       [ 1.000e-01,  1.000e-02,  8.000e+00],
       [ 2.000e-01,  2.000e-02,  1.000e+01],
       ....
       [ 2.500e+00,  8.063e+01,  3.900e+01]])
```

But this is quite different from passing a string (even a py2 bytestring) to `np.array`.

You could use `eval` to convert the bytestring to a list of lists, and then make the array from that:

```
In [298]: eval(test)                                                                     
Out[298]: 
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0.0, 0.01, -1.0],
 [0.1, 0.01, 8.0],
 [0.2, 0.02, 10.0],
 ...
 [2.5, 80.63, 39.0]]
In [299]: np.array(eval(test))                                                           
Out[299]: 
array([[ 0.000e+00,  0.000e+00,  0.000e+00],
       [ 0.000e+00,  1.000e-02, -1.000e+00],
       [ 1.000e-01,  1.000e-02,  8.000e+00],
        ...
       [ 2.500e+00,  8.063e+01,  3.900e+01]])
```

Comment: I added an additional edit. It seems that the type(test) in python2 = list, but type(test) in python3 = bytes. The code is identical but produces different results. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: The issue then lies in how `test` is created or loaded.  In py2 it is a list (of lists) which converts to numpy directly.  In py3 it is a bytestring (note the `b'...'`), which cannot be made into a numeric array directly.

Comment: Thanks! The answer from Valdi_Bo above worked for me.